# refresh an image in html automatically in text type

Tags: python, html, image, refresh

I'm uploading a live graph into html page (CPU usage plotting in line), it's not a static image. it's dynamic so i need to update it every second. is there any way to do this in html text type, as i don't have much language in java script or other languages,
I need it in text type for refreshing an image.

Comment: BTW: without JavaScript you can refresh only full page using [meta tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_http_equiv.asp). Eventually you could create `<iframe>` with page which has only image and which uses meta tag to reload this page with image.